# How do I remove photos from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, iphone, storage, pictures

I'm uploading all of the pictures from my iTunes to Picasa. Afterwards, I would like to delete all of the photos off of the phone, and the local copies stored in iTunes (I need the disk space). I want all of the old ones gone (since they'll be backed up), but I also want it to start syncing all of the new photos that I take from this point forward.

How do I do this?

Comment: If I was you I would just do is : First plug in the USB cored the Sinc you Iphone/pod then go to the photo album and you will find yours pictures delet the ones you don't won't simply press bin then if you really don't won't any one to see go to junk and do the same Age 12 Ryan Revy Sorry for spellings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Deleting all photos from your iTunes.

1. Select all photos. (Select -> All Photos or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Right click on the selection and click Delete, if asked, choose to remove them from your PC.

### Deleting all photos from your iPhone.

1. When you click "import photos" while syncing your iPhone it asks you if you want to keep the originals or delete them (meaning on the iPhone). Just click to delete the originals.
2. **Alternative**: Go into your iPhone and clear all photos.

— http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=344835

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be anything tricky about this. Once they are backed up, delete them from your phone and from iTunes by selecting them all and deleting them. You can also check which folders your iTunes photo library is pointing to, and remove the pictures from there as well.

When you delete the photos from your iTunes library, it should ask you if you want to delete them only from the library, or from the computer as well.

For importing, the iPhone doesn't sync pictures the way it syncs music. You have to set up your computer to import the pictures automatically to a specific folder (like you would with a digital camera) and then point your iTunes photo library to that directory.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what was confusing me. I don't think I was syncing photos after all, which I think is why I didn't see any photos in iTunes.

Comment: Yea, you have to import them yourself as you would a digital camera, then add that folder to your iTunes library. Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

If your photos are backed up to the Cloud, the only way to delete them from your phone is to restore you phone as new and NOT sync your photos. Simply download them to your phone using the same method you would a camera shot. I've been on the phone with Apple techs for a whole day trying to resolve this.